# How can I isolate $y$ in $125=\left({\sqrt{y^2+\left(\frac{x+5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3+\left({\sqrt{y^2+\left (\frac{x-5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I'm trying to find a method to isolate $y$ in this formula that I could use for any other numerical magnitudes or even positions when radicals are involved in this way

$$125=\left({\sqrt{y^2+\left(\frac{x+5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3+\left({\sqrt{y^2+\left (\frac{x-5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3$$

Comment: Have you tried to actually solve it? What methods have failed you?

Comment: I can solve it giving x a value, but I wish to isolate it to use this in an algorithm where x will be diferent in each execution.

Comment: Isolating $y$ is quite doable, its just that you are going to have to square the equation a few times and use the binomial theorem a lot. Even then you are going to end up with a high degree polynomial that doesn't have an explicit formula. You would have to make some substitutions to get anything useful...

Comment: I cannot write an answer right now, but it seems a candidate for Taylor expansion, because you want a function, rather than a numerical pointwise aproximation. You can automate implicit differentiation with software, e.g. Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = 10u$, $y = 5v$ and $w = u^2+v^2+\frac14$. The equation at hand can be rewritten as
$$\sqrt{v^2+\left(u+\frac12\right)^2}^3 + \sqrt{v^2+\left(u-\frac12\right)^2}^3 = 1 \iff \sqrt{w+u}^3 + \sqrt{w-u}^3 = 1$$
Let $f_{ab} = a\sqrt{w+u}^3 + b\sqrt{w-u}^3 - 1$ where $a, b \in \{ +, - \}$. 
Above equations becomes
$$f_{++} = 0 \quad\implies\quad f_{++}f_{+-}f_{-+}f_{--} = 0$$
When one expand LHS of last expression, all square roots cancel out. One get

$$36u^2w^4 - 4w^3 + 24u^4w^2 - 12u^2w + 4u^6 + 1 = 0$$

For fixed $x$, $u$ will be constant. Above equation becomes a quartic equation in $w$.
One can use formula discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to express $w$ in radicals.
Since $y = \pm 5\sqrt{ w - u^2 - \frac14}$,
one can express $y$ in radicals too.

The problem is the formula for $y$ is a real mess (too horrible to reproduce here).
I doubt it has any practical use.

Comment: I can't be more grateful. Even it's an old question and somehow I loosed it in my memory, it's fair to mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 5):

I should not try to isolate $y$ since this would give a monster.

The first thing I should do is to replace $y^2=Y$ and consider that I look for the zero of equation $$f(Y)=\left({\sqrt{Y+\left(\frac{x+5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3+\left({\sqrt{Y+\left (\frac{x-5}{2}\right)^2}}\right)^3-125$$

Thsi equation does not show real root except for the range $-5\leq x \leq 5$ and $Y(-x)=Y(x)$. Replacing $x$ by a number leads to $Y$ and $Y(x)$ is a nice smooth curve. So, my idea would be

- Generate a table of values for $Y(x)$,as for example
  $$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
   x & Y \\
   0.0 & 9.49901 \\
   0.5 & 9.41167 \\
   1.0 & 9.14917 \\
  1.5 & 8.71001 \\
   2.0 & 8.09152 \\
   2.5 & 7.28945 \\
   3.0 & 6.29726 \\
  3.5 & 5.10467 \\
   4.0 & 3.69431 \\
  4.5 & 2.03175 \\
   5.0 & 0.
  \end{array}
  \right)$$
- Build a cubic spline which, for a given $x$, will give you a good estimate $Y_0$ of the solution. Otherwise, use as an approximation $$ Y_0=\frac{2 \sqrt[3]{2}-1}{4} (5-x)(5+x)$$ In the worst case, a table lookup and linear interpolation would provide areasonable estimate of $Y$.
- Polish the solution using Newton method starting with $Y_0$ (notice that $f'(Y)$ is quite simple). The method would converge in very very few iterations.

For illustration purposes, let us consider $x=1.2345$; the approximate parabola gives an estimate $Y_0=9.1034$. Newton method generates the following iterates $$Y_1=8.96564$$ $$Y_2=8.96533$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: Even if it could be a monster, I would like to know how can I go for it. And it's enough for values of x between 0 and 5.

Comment: Anyway thank you Claude for your inspiration!

Comment: Claude, thanks for your new edit. I'll need to remove the dust of my algebra notes when I was an student.
As for the task of finding those polynomials, it seems to me that it will not be such a "pleasure"... :D.
Thanks again.

Comment: @JosepAlacid : Not a real pleasure ... but a lot of fun !